# Contributing to Python: edit git/cloned code or installed code?

Tags: python, open-source, github

I would like to contribute to open source Python project hosted on github.
But the code base comes as module that needs to be installed using pip or smth like this.
Which means I do "git clone", "setup.py install" the code will be placed after installation into another (non repo) folder.
The question is which folder I should edit/commit code then and what's the standard solution foe such a multi-folder issue.

Comment: Did you ask on some python-developer specific mailing list or wiki ??

Comment: You usually edit in the git repository, and it's usually possible to test the code right there, without installing.

Comment: Edit the code in the repository, and install it to test (if necessary).

Answer (score 3):

You'd normally do **setup.py develop** or **pip install -e** .
So you don't want the installer to copy it anywhere else.
Using this mode, a special link file is created in your site-packages directory. This link points back to the current folder or 'root package'. Any changes you make to the software here will be reflected immediately without having to do an install again.